# How to remove unwanted fields logstash (ELK)

Tags: logstash, elk

How can I remove unnecessary fields? Type:
agent.ephemeral_id agent.id winlog.provider_guid

I tried, but Kibana stops showing logs at all

```
- drop_fields:
      fields: ["date_created", "ecs.version", "agent.version", "agent.type", "agent.id"]
```

In logstash I have these configs: filter.conf, input.conf, output.conf

Filter:

```
filter {
    if "winsrvad" in [tags] {
    if [winlog][event_id] != "5136" and [winlog][event_id] !=ent_id] != "4729" and id] != "4734" {
    drop { }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using prune to blacklist the 'unnecessary fields' when the condition is met.

See documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutate;like below

```yaml
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "date_created", "ecs.version", "agent.version", "agent.type", "agent.id"]
  }
```

Comment: I tried to do that, it didn't work. How can I contact you?

Comment: Please share your complete pipeline configuration and sample data

Answer (score -2):

The `drop` option will ignore the entire log, you can use `remove_field` option inside the `mutate` plugin instead.

For example:

```rb
mutate {
  remove_field => [
    "date_created",
    "[ecs][version]",
    "[agent][version]",
    "[agent][type]",
    "[agent][id]"
  ]
}
```

I have written a detailed tutorial for this: [How to Remove Field in Logstash](https://dminhvu.com/logstash-remove-field).